# How to create a DataGrid display in android?

Tags: android

Hai any one please tell me is there any possibility to create a DataGrid in android ,if yes mean please help me with some code snippets,or give some related web urls.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by DataGrid?

Comment: this is a gimme-teh-codez question, try writing code first after all you are paid for it, ..  and then if you have problems ask them here.

Comment: Here is an Android DataGrid component : http://www.androidjetpack.com/Home/AndroidDataGrid

Answer (score 9):

Book.java

```
package com.dgrid;

public class Book {
    String title;
    String author;

    public Book(String title, String author) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }
    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<ListView  
    android:id="@+id/bookListView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:divider="#ffffff" 
    />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/widget0"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_toRightOf="@android:id/icon"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<com.dgrid.ListItemView
android:id="@+id/title"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="150px"
android:text="Title"
android:textSize="10sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textColor="#ff000000"
/>
```

ListItemView.java

```
package com.dgrid;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListItemView extends TextView {
    private boolean isHeader = false;
    private Paint linePaint;

    public ListItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public ListItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public ListItemView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public void init(){
        linePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        linePaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    }
    public boolean isHeader() {
        return isHeader;
    }

    public void setHeader(boolean isHeader) {
        this.isHeader = isHeader;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if(isHeader){
            canvas.drawColor(Color.parseColor("#AAFFFF99"));
        }
        canvas.drawLine(0, 0, getMeasuredWidth(), 0,linePaint);
        canvas.drawLine(0, getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight(),linePaint);
        canvas.drawLine(0,0, 0, getMeasuredHeight(),linePaint);
    }
}
```

DatagridActivity.java

```
package com.dgrid;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class DatagridActivity extends Activity {
    Context mContext;
    Book[] books = {new Book("Title","Author"),new Book("Clean Code","Uncle Bob"),new Book("Face 2.0","Allen Cooper")};
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mContext = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ListView bookListView =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.bookListView);
        LitemItemAdapter mcqListAdapter = new LitemItemAdapter(this,R.layout.row,books);
        bookListView.setAdapter(mcqListAdapter);
    }
    class LitemItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Book>{

        public LitemItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                Book[] objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        }
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {

                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            }
            Book item = books[position];
            if (item != null) {
                    ListItemView titleView = (ListItemView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
                    ListItemView authorView = (ListItemView) v.findViewById(R.id.author);
                    if(position == 0){
                        titleView.setHeader(true);
                        authorView.setHeader(true);
                    }
                    if(titleView != null){
                        titleView.setText(item.getTitle());
                    }
                    if(authorView != null){
                        authorView.setText(item.getAuthor());
                    }
            }
            return v;
        }       

    }
}
```

Comment: Haven't tried out this code but I think you could do without widget0 to wrap the textview. Also is title hardcoded to 150px? What happens if it's a long title for one row, it won't look like a datagrid no more, no?