# Android equivalent to Windows Mobile Datagrid control?

Tags: android, datagrid

I everyone. I'm very new to Android development and I want to develop an application that uses a local database. I want to show the results of queries in a DataGrid like object.

The UI would be somewhat similar to this.

[image: http://i5.photobucket.com/albums/y163/marco2530/img1.jpg]

Is it possible to develop this kind of UI in Android? If so how can I accomplish this? Are there good tutorials I can follow?

Thank you very much.

Marco Sousa

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a DataGrid display in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011237/how-to-create-a-datagrid-display-in-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) is probably what you want. You have complete control over the presentation of each row through the [`ListAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html) that your app supplies, which you can use to present each row's data as a series of fixed width columns. Helpers such as [`CursorAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) will give you a starting point for presenting data from a local database.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing strictly identical to a `DataGrid`. There is `GridView`, which gives you rows and columns, but that's designed more as a two-dimensional `ListView`. There is `TableLayout`, which gives you rows and columns, but it is not designed to handle an arbitrary number of rows.

Comment: Thanks Mark! Wonder how useful would be the code given here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011237/how-to-create-a-datagrid-display-in-android

Answer (score 0):

There's a quite nice overview of available views including screen-shots and code examples in the tutorial section on the android developers site - this might help you in choosing the right layout:
[Hello Views](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/index.html)